# How can I clear the image cache after my user scroll down the screen, and reload if it scroll up?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I clear the image cache after my user scroll down the screen, and reload if it scroll up?

I have a lazy listview while the user scroll down the news cards with imagens are loading from web. when many imagens loaded around 500, the app begin be "slow", I guess it's bacease there many imagens in cache, My imagens are 100pxs only.

Answer (score 1):

Important note, it is unlikely that simply having more images in your image cache will result in bad performance, especially if you are displaying them with a `ListView.builder()`. Check you are not running in debug mode, which severly hurts performance, and make sure you profile before trying to optimize performance.

That being said, if you know the the key for an image in Flutter's image cache, you can remove the image by calling

```dart
imageCache!.evict(key);
```

Different types of `ImageProvider` have different keys, but given that you are getting your images from the web, I'm assuming you're using `NetworkImage` (or `Image.network` which uses `NetworkImage` under the hood).

You could then create a Widget that wraps an `Image`, and evicts it from the cache once it is disposed. Perhaps something like this:

```dart
class DisposingNetworkImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final NetworkImage image;
  // boilerplate
}

class DisposingNetworkImageState extends State<DisposingNetworkImage> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    imageCache!.evict(widget.image);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext) => Image(
    image: widget.image,
  );
}
```

Then you can use this in your other widgets like:

```dart
DisposingNetworkImage(image: NetworkImage('https://example.com/my-image'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try using CachedNetworkImage widget from `cached_network_image` plugin.

It takes cacheHeight and cacheWidth params. Don't forget to provide these values.

Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image.